# Why is this CSS class styling order-dependent?

Tags: css

```
.container {
   border: 4px solid;
}
```

and another class

```
.border-red {
   border-color:red;
}
```

and my html

```
<div class="container border-red"> </div>
```

The border color does not apply to the element unless i put the `.border-red` class before
`.container`

Please check for demo [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MurWade/qf9trLo9/)

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that this

```
.container {
   border: 4px solid;
}
```

is actually shorthand for

```
.container {
   border-width: 4px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: ** current font color **;
}
```

Consequently, the later style overrides the previous border-color declaration.

[**Border @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border)

Answer (score 2):

It is order dependent because `border:` is a shorthand of `border-style:` + `border-width:` + `border-color:`.

Answer (score 1):

this happens because the `.container` class overrides the colour of the border defined in the `.border-red` class

Without using `!important` I would change like so

```
.container {
   border-width: 4px;
   border-style: solid;
}

.border-red {
   border-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The border property is a shortcut that sets (and overwrite) three properties at once:

- `border-width` (Default value `medium`)
- `border-style` (Default value `none`)
- `border-color` (Default value is the value of the element's color property)

Declaring `border` after `border-color` overwrites the three properties even if you do not explicitly specify all three values.

The solution is to break your rule and list only the properties that you want to change. This works regardless of the order of rules:

```
.border-red {
    border-color:red;
}
.container {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px ;
}
```